# prove that the points $Q, R, S$ are non-collinear.

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

**the question**

Let $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ be a parallelepiped, $O$ its centre and the points $M \in (AB), N \in (AD), P \in (A A')$ Denote by $Q, R, S$ symmetrical to the point $O$ of the points $M, N,$ respectively $P$. Knowing that $OM \cap (ADA')=\{Q\}, ON \cap (ABB') = \{R\}, OP \cap (ABC) =\{S\} $

a) prove that the points $Q, R, S$ are non-collinear;

b) prove that $(QRS) || (A'BD)$ and determine the ratio of the areas of the triangles $QRS$ and $A'BD$

**my idea**

for point a) I have been able to demonstrate that $D', A, Q$ are collinear by supposing they aren't collinear then saying that they all 3 $\in (AD'A), (D'AB)$, two different planes, which means they are collinear.

Similarly we get that $R, A,B'$ are collinear and $S, A,C$ are collinear.

I don't know what to do forward, I'm stuck. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: If $QRS$ were collinear then lines $OQ$, $OR$, $OS$ would lie on the same plane, which is not the case as point $P$ doesn't lie on plane $OMN$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca thank you for your idea. May i ask why P doesnt lie on that plane? Is any demonstration?

Comment: Points $A$ and $C$ lie on opposite sides of line $MN$, hence they also lie on opposite sides of plane $OMN$. Points $A'$ and $C$ also lie on opposite sides of plane $OMN$, because $O$ is the midpoint of $A'C$. Hence segment $AA'$ doesn't intersect plane $OMN$ and $P\in(AA')$ cannot lie on plane $OMN$.